# if i do app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); it always opens index.html file in public .

Tags: node.js, express, post, node-modules

i am unable to open register.html file in public when server started using post method.
by default during starting of server if index.html file is missing then it gives CANNOT/GET.
so help me to figure it out ..how to open register .html

Answer (score 0):

express.static middleware accepts only GET request. you need to seperately define a route, if you want the file in POST method.